# Visual studio targets the wrong location for dll files

Tags: visual-studio, dll

i'm trying to create my first project with visual studio in c++.
When i'm trying to run the project i'm getting this message:
[image: console after trying to run]

visual studio tries to locate these files in a directory that they don't exist in, how can i change it?

(i.e. instead of C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll to C:\Windows\Sys32\ntdll.dll)

Comment: Nothing wrong here, the program was built to target x86 and thus runs in 32-bit mode.  So loads the operating system DLLs from syswow64.  wow64 is the windows-on-windows emulator that a 32-bit program needs to run on a 64-bit OS.

Comment: @HansPassant so if it is not the problem, how do i fix it? the program says i don't have these dll, but i have them in another directory. What do i do?

Comment: It does not say that when you see "loaded".  The debugger merely informs you that it does not have a PDB file for the DLL.  Contains debugging info.  That's fine, you don't want to debug the operating system.